# Oscillation period of a hard stick hung at both ends

Tags: experimental-physics, oscillators

[image]

Hi all,

Does anyone know how this set-up will affect the oscillation period of the system? We have been measuring using timer and this set-up always yields longer period than standard pendulum oscillation formula. For example: 4.4s vs 4.0s.

I am unable to work out the exact formula. I really appreciate any help from you.

Comment: If the stick does not rotate then the period should be that of the simple pendulum. What measurements did you make? What results did you get?

Comment: If you're errors are always like that 10%, check your systematic errors.

Comment: We measured oscillation period in perpendicular direction and then compared it with the direction shown in the picture. The initial swing angles are almost identical in both directions. We consistently got the deviation of around 10% 4.4s vs 4.0s. We measured using a timer to time 10 round trips of the oscillation.

Comment: I have an idea. Do you have a photograph of the apparatus? Better still a video of the oscillations? What are the dimensions of the stick?  Specifically I need the cross section dimensions. Also the length of the strings.

Comment: @ sammy gerbil, I am not allowed to share, it is a crane in a confidential factory. Technically, you can imagine it as 2 crane moving in a synchronized pattern having hooks connected with each other by a hard metal bar.

Answer (score 0):

The standard pendulum oscillation period relies on the small-angle approximation. If you're swinging the stick at a large angle (larger than 30 degrees from the vertical), then an increase of 10 percent in the period is perfectly reasonable, as shown in Fig. 1 here: http://users.df.uba.ar/sgil/physics_paper_doc/papers_phys/mechan/Pendulo2.pdf

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: @VinhVo What was the initial swing angle?

Comment: Around 15degree I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Although, ideally, the period should be the same, there are some differences between the two oscillation modes (let's call them parallel and perpendicular) that could affect the period.

Some of the differences have to do with potential difficulties in keeping the parallel oscillations in plane, but that probably can be achieved.

Another difference is that, in the parallel mode, the angle between the strings and the stick is changing, which implies additional friction. If it is significant, it could affect the Q and the period. You can compare Q by checking how quickly the oscillations decay in each oscillation mode.